# How do I change the background of an A-element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, telerik

I have the following html markup:

```
<table class="rwTitlebarControls" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 16px;">
                <a class="rwIcon" style="background: transparent url(Images/ic_icon_16.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <em unselectable="on">Title</em>
            </td>
            <td nowrap="" style="white-space: nowrap;">
            </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to change the image url of the <a>-element with the class **rwIcon** using jQuery, but I can't seem to find the .rwIcon.

I can find the containing table without problem using:

```
$('table.rwTitlebarControls');
```

but both the following selections fail to return the element I need

```
$('a.rwIcon')

$('.rwIcon')
```

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:** This HTML is auto-generated by Telerik's RadComponents and is not something I can change or control, so please just try to answer the question and refrain from commenting on the quality of the markup. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting the A tag, or is it just not changing the background? Try alert($('.rwIcon').length);

Comment: Can you use anchor like that ? Anchor should have an ending tag and href attribute imho...

Comment: 1. you use a table for markup: wrong. 2. you use inline css: wrong.

Comment: It is a corect syntaxis of $('.rwIcon')
Problem must be somewear outside.
Can you give all html?

Comment: The markup is auto-generated by Telerik Radcomponents

Answer (score 2):

This does work:

```
$('.rwIcon')
```

But the a tag with that class is empty (i.e. it has no content)

This works:

```
<a class="rwIcon" style="background: transparent url(Images/ic_icon_16.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;">SOME CONTENT</a>
```

With this script:

```
$(".rwIcon").css({backgroundColor:"#000000"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I hade the correct element, I just didn't identify it as such. The following script changes the background image of the a-tag:

```
function ChangeWindowIcon(icon) {
    icon = 'url(Images/ic_' + icon + '_16.png)';
    $('a.rwIcon').css({ 'background-image': icon });
}
```